# Zabbix-agent: cannot stat 'filename.log': [13] Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, files

I have installed Zabbix-server and zabbix-agent and trying to add trigger to check log file.

But in `/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log` I got the same error every time:

```
10832:20131008:125634.180 cannot stat '/home/teamcity/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/logs/catalina.out.test': [13] Permission denied
10832:20131008:125634.180 Active check [log["/home/teamcity/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/logs/catalina.out.test","ERROR"]] is not supported. Disabled.
```

I chmoded and chowned file with:

```
# ls -lh /home/teamcity/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/logs/catalina.out.test
-rwsrwsrwx 1 zabbix zabbix 229M Oct  8 12:09 /home/teamcity/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/logs/catalina.out.test
```

Item created with type Zabbix-agent (active) and have key:

```
log["/home/teamcity/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/logs/catalina.out.test","ERROR"]
```

Trigger:

```
{lms-teamcity:log["/home/teamcity/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/logs/catalina.out.test","ERROR"].str(ERROR)}=1
```

Can somebody explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try disabling selinux!

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be, that you only adjusted the permissions for the file itself, but the parent directory is inaccessible for the `zabbix` user.

To make this more visible, just try it out on a shell:

- Get root permissions first

  - sudo-based: `sudo su -`
  - pure su: `su -`
- Switch to the `zabbix` user and give him a shell as there might be none set in `/etc/passwd`:
  `su -s /bin/bash zabbix`
- Try to access the file with the zabbix user:

  `ls -l /home/teamcity/opt/apache-tomcat-5.5.36/logs/catalina.out.test`

The problem is simply and very likely missing permissions on the parent directories of the logfile.